# Error: Cannot match any routes. When lazy loading an Angular auxilary route

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-router, router-outlet, angular-auxiliary-routes

I am trying to make a nested child route call to load in an auxilary router outlet, but I cannot seem to make it work. I keep getting the `Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment:'header/secondary/abc'`

**StackBlitz Link:** https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-t3x2cw?file=src/app/header/header.component.ts

**My expected result** is to have the Secondary and Abc modules/components load on the left in the normal router outlet `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`, and the Test component to load on the right in the aux route `<router-outlet name="aux"></router-outlet>` . Like in the image below.
[image: Trying to load the Test component in the auxilary route to the right of the ABC component]

Answer (score 2):

There are a few problems:

First, notice the `header.component.html`'s content:

```html
<div>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
<div>
  <router-outlet name="aux"></router-outlet>
</div>
```

and `header` component's routes:

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: HeaderComponent,
    children: [
      { path: '', redirectTo: 'secondary', pathMatch: 'full' },
      {
        path: 'secondary',
        loadChildren: () =>
          import('./../secondary/secondary.module').then(
            (m) => m.SecondaryModule
          ),
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

there is a mismatch between what the component's view wants to show and that the route configuration describes. As a rule of thumb, what's in the view of component `X` must correspond with what the component `X` requires in the route configuration. In this case, the `header` component's view requires a **named outlet**, `aux`, but in the route configuration there are only paths for **primary outlets**(i.e `secondary`).

So, if you want your component to handle multiple outlets, you can do something like this:

```js
// header.component route configuration

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: HeaderComponent,
    children: [
      { path: '', redirectTo: 'secondary', pathMatch: 'full' },
      {
        path: 'secondary',
        loadChildren: () =>
          import('./../secondary/secondary.module').then(
            (m) => m.SecondaryModule
          ),
      },
      
      // !
      {
        path: 'foo',
        outlet: 'aux',
        component: FooComponent,
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

and the `navigate()` method would look like this:

```js
navigate() {
    this.router.navigate([
      "header",
      {
        // key-value pairs
        // `key`: the **name** of the outlet
        // `value`: the paths defined for the outlet
        outlets: {
          primary: ["secondary", "abc"],
          aux: ["foo"]
        }
      }
    ]);
  }
```

[StackBlitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-7c7ihx?file=src%2Fapp%2Fheader%2Fheader.component.ts).

Also, if you'd like to read more about Angular Router, I'd recommend having a look at:

- [Angular Router: Revealing some interesting facts and features](https://indepth.dev/posts/1379/angular-router-revealing-some-interesting-facts-and-features)
- [Demystifying angular/router: what is RouterScroller and why is it useful ?](https://indepth.dev/posts/1366/demystifying-angular-router-what-is-routerscroller-and-why-is-it-useful-2)